# Ceiling fan lights wont turn off?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

Moved into a new home and theres a hunter ceiling fan in the room. When I put light bulbs in It they dont turn off. The pull switch dims and brightens the lights but doesnt not turn them off. There is no light switch for the fan. I was told that there was a 3-way switch that turned off the outlets but they removed the switches and have them constantly on (they were half outlets at one point). Any ideas on why this could be? Couldve the 3-way switch controlled the ceiling fan but now it's hard wired and way to get around it?

Comment: I would assume the pull switch in the light kit is defective, probably worn out.

Comment: People are often annoyed by switched receptacles and defeat them. However, removing the standard, expected light switch violates building codes, because you are not allowed to use *a method only you know* as the only means to turn on lights.  The usual switch must be present and work.